# React hook equivalent to callback function after setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react (before hooks) when we set state we could call a function after state had been set as such:

```
this.setState({}, () => {//Callback})
```

What is the equivalent of this with hooks?

I tried doing this

```
const [currentRange, setCurrentRange] = useState("24h");

setCurrentRange(someRange, () => console.log('hi'))
```

But this did not work

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook can be used to invoke a function when some state change. If you pass it `currentRange` in an array as second argument, the function will only be invoked when `currentRange` change.

You can also create your own custom hook that uses the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to keep track of if it's the first time the effect is being run, so that you can skip the first invocation.

**Example**

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

function useEffectSkipFirst(fn, arr) {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirst.current) {
      isFirst.current = false;
      return;
    }

    return fn();
  }, arr);
}

function App() {
  const [currentRange, setCurrentRange] = useState("24h");

  useEffectSkipFirst(
    () => {
      console.log("hi");
    },
    [currentRange]
  );

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setCurrentRange(Math.floor(Math.random() * 24) + 1 + "h")}
    >
      Change range ({currentRange})
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you pass multiple functions in place of `fn` in `useEffectSkipFirst`? what would that look like? getting `not a function error` for an additional param `fn2`

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel You could pass just one function that in turn calls both your functions, e.g. `useEffectSkipFirst(() => { fn1(); fn2(); }, [currentRange]);`

Answer (score 3):

You can use useEffect/useLayoutEffect to achieve this:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 1) {
      document.title = 'Threshold of over 1 reached.';
    } else {
      document.title = 'No threshold reached.';
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you are looking for an out of the box solution, check out [this custom hook](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback) that works like useState but accepts as second parameter a callback function:

```
import useStateWithCallback from 'use-state-with-callback';

const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallback(0, count => {
    if (count > 1) {
      document.title = 'Threshold of over 1 reached.';
    } else {
      document.title = 'No threshold reached.';
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It can be installed via `npm install use-state-with-callback`