# Update a single property of object from array using useState() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects in todos state hook. And I want to change a single property if it is completed. Seems I can update it but without using setTodos. I am a React beginner.

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const addTodoHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.length < 2) return;
    setTodos([...todos, { id: Date.now(), text: input, isComplete: false }]);
    setInput("");
  };

  const removeHandler = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };

 const completeHandler = (id) => {

    // working without setTodo()
    // errors when added setTodo()
     todos.map((todo) =>
       todo.id === id ? console.log((todo.isComplete = !todo.isComplete)) : ""
     );

  };

      <div className="todolist">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            id={todo.id}
            text={todo.text}
            removeHandler={removeHandler}
            completeHandler={completeHandler}
            isComplete={todo.isComplete}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

47 | <div className="todolist">
  48 |   {todos.map((todo) => (
  49 |     <Todo
> 50 |       key={todo.id}
     | ^  51 |       id={todo.id}
  52 |       text={todo.text}
  53 |       removeHandler={removeHandler}
`
when added setTodos() :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this inside `completeHandler()` first create a new array using `map()` method and inside `map()` method update the `isComplete` for the current `todo` and simply return the updated value like:

```
var updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) => todo.id === id ? {
  ...todo,
  isComplete: !todo.isComplete
} : todo);
```

Then inside `setTodos()` just return this new `updatedTodos` array like:

```
setTodos(updatedTodos);
```

You can also do this in one-line like:

```
setTodos(todos.map((todo) => todo.id === id ? { ...todo, isComplete: !todo.isComplete } : todo));
```

But the previous code provides more readability and also helps in better debugging if you want to check each variable line by line.