# Why is my state variable not updating despite setting it with the provided method?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
  ...
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);


  // form submission handler
  const handleSubmit = event => {

    // [DEBUG] ////////////////////////
    console.log('entered handleSubmit');
    ////////////////////////////////////

    event.preventDefault();

    const isValid = !!(values.firstName && values.lastName && values.email);
    setSubmitted(isValid); // ???? changes not being reflected in submitted ??????


    // [DEBUG] //////////////////////////////////////////
    console.log('[isValid]', isValid);  // true
    console.log('[submitted]', submitted); // false ???

    console.log('exiting handleSubmit');
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  };
  ...
```

As you can see, the code tries to update the state variable. However, the changes are not being reflected. Any explanations why?

Comment: `setSubmitted` is asynchronous.

Comment: Ah okay. So how would I go about solving this riddle?

Comment: State is updated asynchrnously. State and props are constants within a specific render of a react component. Component will have to re-render in order for it to see the updated state or props.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Comment: Well, I have a form that should be using the updated value upon submission... But pressing the submit button doesn't work as it should for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

State is updated asynchronously.
You can catch the updated state value inside useEffect().

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(submitted);
}, [submitted]);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow already has many questions and answers about this behavior. Part of what makes Stack Overflow a great resource is that we consolidate questions about the same issue into just a few Q&A pairs so that searches find those instead of 500 different questions and answers. If you see comments on a question starting with "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link, please navigate to that link and see if you think the question is answered. If so, please refrain from answering the question. Thanks.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the advice. However, on the flip side, many a time these so-called "duplicates" have been suggested based on certain keywords, without the "suggestor" really bothering to view the content to see if things are actually duplicated.