# React - in a functional component, using hooks, can I execute a piece of code once after one setState() successfully changes state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`setState` updates state asynchronously. It's my understanding that, when using a class component, you can do something like this to ensure certain code is executed after one `setState` updates state:

```js
setState({color: red}, callbackThatExecutesAfterStateIsChanged);
```

I'm using a functional component & hooks. I'm aware, here, `useEffect()`'s callback will execute **everytime** after `color` state changes **and on initial execution.**

```js
useEffect(callback, [color]);
```

How can I replicate similar behaviour as the class component example - that is, to execute a chunk of code **once** after **one** `setState()` successfully changes state **and not on initial execution**?

Comment: one after the first render ?

Comment: Similar Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56247433/5669120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Comment: Thanks @KetanRamteke. It doesn't answer my question because, as my question demonstrates, I know how to use `setState`. My question is about replicating the same behaviour as the first code snippet with hooks in a functional component

Comment: Why would you need that anyway? `useEffect` can solve most of the real-world problems

Comment: @bravemaster I need functionA to receive the latest update of stateA. I don't want functionA to execute on initial execution. It'd be preferable is functionA only executes when stateA updates once.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, there is no safe way to do this with hooks.
The problem is that you both have to read and set an `initialized` state in order to ignore the first update:

```
const takeFirstUpdate = (callback, deps) => {
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  const [wasTriggered, setWasTriggered] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized) {
      setInitialized(true);
      return;
    }
    if (wasTriggered) {
      return;
    }
    callback();
    setWasTriggered(true);
  }, [initialized, wasTriggered]);
};
```

While the hook looks like it works, it will trigger itself again by calling `setInitialized(true)` in the beginning, thus also triggering the callback.

You could remove the initialized value from the deps array and the hook would work for now - however this would cause an [`exhaustive-deps` linting error](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880). The hook might break in the future as it is not an "official" usage of the hooks api, e.g. with updates on the [concurrent rendering feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html) that the React team is working on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below feels hacky. If there's no better alternative, I'm tempted to refactor my component into a class component to make use of the easy way class components allow you to execute code once state has been updated.

Anyway, my current solution is:

The `useRef(arg)` hook returns an object who's `.current` property is set to the value of arg. This object persists throughout the React lifecycle. ([Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)). With this, we can record how many times the `useEffect`'s callback has executed and use this info to stop code inside the callback from executing on initial execution and for a second time. For example:

```js
initialExecution = useRef(true);
[color, setColor] = useState("red");

useEffect(() => {
  setColor("blue");
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (initialExecution.current) {
    initialExecution.current = false;
    return;
  }
  //code that executes when color is updated.
}, [color]);
```