# How to call an API after setting state successfully?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const { Button } = require("@material-ui/core");
const { useState } = require("react");

const Test = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getTodos = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    const resData = await res.json();
    setTodos(resData);
    setLoading(false);
  };
  const getUsers = async () => {
    setTodos([]);
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(loading)
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const resData = await res.json();
    setUsers(resData);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        disabled={loading}
        onClick={getTodos}
      >
        Get Todos
      </Button>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        disabled={loading}
        onClick={getUsers}
      >
        Get Users
      </Button>
      {todos.map((item) => (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      ))}
      {users.map((item) => (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Since setLoading is async and does not return any promise, is there any way to successfully set the loading state and then finally fetch the data **without using an useEffect with the dependency of loading**. I think using an useEffect for the loading state will become complicated because the loading state is used for multiple api calls.

Comment: I don't see how the current implementation would not work. You could `setLoading` before calling `getUsers`?

Comment: If we look at `getTodos()` for example, the `setLoading(true)` and the `fetch()` might be called asynchronously instead of one after the other. I actually want it to be synchronous.

Comment: What you are doing is correct, you only set todo's to `response` and loading to `false` after the fetch, setting state is `async` but shouldn't cause problems in your situation. If you want to set loading after setting the todo's, you will have to use `useEffect`, but your code looks good.

Comment: so if somehow `setLoading()` takes time, the user will be able to click the button multiple times before the component re-renders.  I kind of don't want that to happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`setState\` callback on react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247433/how-to-use-setstate-callback-on-react-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try to implement like this.

```
import "./styles.css";

const { Button } = require("@material-ui/core");
const { useState } = require("react");

const Test = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  // const getTodos = async () => {
  //   setLoading(true);
  //   const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  //   const resData = await res.json();
  //   setTodos(resData);
  //   setLoading(false);
  // };
  // const getUsers = async () => {
  //   setTodos([]);
  //   setLoading(true);
  //   console.log(loading);
  //   const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  //   const resData = await res.json();
  //   setUsers(resData);
  //   setLoading(false);
  // };

  const getTodos = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const getTodosData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
      const resData = await res.json();
      setTodos(resData);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getTodosData();
  };

  const getUsers = () => {
    setTodos([]);
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(loading);

    const getUsersData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const resData = await res.json();
      setUsers(resData);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getUsersData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        disabled={loading}
        onClick={getTodos}
      >
        Get Todos
      </Button>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        variant="contained"
        disabled={loading}
        onClick={getUsers}
      >
        Get Users
      </Button>
      {todos.map((item) => (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      ))}
      {users.map((item) => (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Will that make any difference though? if we look at `getTodos()` for example, the `setLoading(true)` and `getTodosData()` still might be called asynchronously instead of one after the other

Comment: @auditore There is no difference, this just delegating it to a different function. There is no problem with your current code.