# How to execute call after setState finish?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Got this call:

```
setPou2({ ...pou2, imgId: po?.imgId2 }, () => {})
```

and it raise an error:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
```

Comment: Is `setPou2` is a state. If it is, then It only expects single argument

Comment: Check out this q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56247433/16806649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to you are passing 2nd argument of call. `setPou2({...pou2, imgId:po?.imgId2})` this will not raise any error.

If you want callback function after change in state you need to use `useEffect` by passing that particular `state` as array.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  // function you want to run
},[pou2])
```

or you can check this [useStateWithCallback](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback)