# function with second argument react hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

all i want is, after changing the state, i want to run the second argument..

without hooks.. this is what it looks like

```
state = {
  gasTypeFrom: '',
}

setModal = item => {
    setState({ gasType: item }, () => {
      renderFrom();
    });
  };
```

this is what i tried with hooks

```
 const [froms, setFroms] = useState({
    gasType: 'Select Value Here',
    displayModal: false,
  });

function setModalFrom(item) {
    useEffect(
      () => {
        setFroms({...froms, gasType: item});
      },
      () => {
        renderModalFrom();
      }
    );
    console.log('setModalFrom()', froms.gasType);
  }
```

how do i do it in hooks with a second argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React hook equivalent to callback function after setting state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895801/react-hook-equivalent-to-callback-function-after-setting-state)

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` takes a function callback and a dependency array, so when a value in the dependency array is updated the effect is fired.

```
const [froms, setFroms] = useState({
  gasType: 'Select Value Here',
  displayModal: false,
});

useEffect(() => {
  renderModalFrom();
}, [froms]); // when a value here updates, effect is run

...somewhere in your code
setFroms({...froms, gasType: item}); // this updates the value
```

[useEffect documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)